# Nashorn - Synchronous Java vs Async Javascript impedance mismatch

Tags: javascript, java, asynchronous, clojure, nashorn

I have a Java Project using Nashorn to run some javascript code specifically to take advantage of some JS libs.

The problem I'm facing is that my Java application is a synchronous app that receives a HTTP request and respond. However in Javascript is common to have libs that receive callbacks.

So my questions are:

- How to deal with the impedance mismatch between sync java and async javascript. Is there a way to wait the callback to be called and only after that respond ?
- How to pass a Java callback to a Javascript function?
- Or is there a way to block the Javascript code until the callback completes?

A example code is below. The project is actually in Clojure, but I'm typing in java for the sake of the example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{customerId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public @ResponseBody Customer getShoppingCart(@PathVariable String customerId) {
    return getById(customerId).toJson();
}

public Customer getById( String id ) {
     nashorn.invokeFunction("javascriptFunction", expectedCallbackFunction)
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For converting asynchronous to synchronous API in Clojure you can use [`promise`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/promise):

Javascript code:

```
function getCustomer(id, clojureCallback) {
  var jsCallback = function(result) { clojureCallback.invoke(result); };
  callHttp("http://api/customer/" + id, jsCallback);
}
```

Clojure code:

```
(def js-engine ...)

(defn get-customer-by-id [id]
  (let [customer-promise (promise)]
    (.invokeFunction js-engine "getCustomer" (object-array [id customer-promise]))
    @customer-promise))
```

Promise result can be submitted by calling [`deliver`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/deliver) function or (as Clojure promise object implements `IFn`) by calling it with the result (`clojureCallback.invoke(result)` in Javascript code). Then the result can be [`deref`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/deref)ed (`@` is a reader macro for `deref`).